# Key press enter event not working in gridlookupedit devexpress

Tags: c#

I'm using gridlookupedit control, but there is 1 problem in this that is I'm filling textbox from gridlookupedit view..while I press enter key at that time my row index changed to default as 0.

This is my code which I have tried:

```
private void GridLookUpEdit_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    try {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13) {
            GridLookUpEdit_Click(sender, e);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void GridLookUpEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        if (sender.Equals(GDrGroup) == true) {
            dec.FillTextBox(gridDrGroup, GDrGroup, new Control[]{txtDrGroupName});
            gridDrParty.Focus();
            gridDrParty.ShowPopup();
        }
        if (sender.Equals(GDrParty) == true) {
            dec.FillTextBox(gridDrParty, GDrParty, new Control[]{txtDrPartyName});
            txtDrCom.Focus();
        }
        if (sender.Equals(GCrGroup) == true) {
            dec.FillTextBox(gridCrGroup, GCrGroup, new Control[]{txtCrGroupName});
            gridCrParty.Focus();
            gridCrParty.ShowPopup();
        }
        if (sender.Equals(GCrParty) == true) {
            dec.FillTextBox(gridCrParty, GCrParty, new Control[]{txtCrPartyName});
            txtCrCom.Focus();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public void FillTextBox(GridLookUpEdit gridlookupedit, GridView view, Control[] con) {
    try {
        if (gridlookupedit.EditValue == null) return;

        for (int i = 0; i <= con.Length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= view.Columns.Count - 1; j++) {
                con[i].Text = view.GetRowCellValue(view.FocusedRowHandle, view.Columns[j]).ToString();
            }
            gridlookupedit.ClosePopup();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```